# Website timeout on mobile webpage

Tags: php, linux, apache, asterisk, http-status-code-504

I have a website running on php.

I access the website on my smartphone. ( In this case, i am using iphone4 chrome mobile browser)

When i click login, the page submits to a another php page and triggers a call to my phone.

The phone call comes in, i answer it and then press the '#' to end the call and brought back to the browser. I get an error 504 error. I am using 3g on my phone. I do this test again using a wifi connection and get the same error.

My php pages are on an apache http server on a linux server running centos 6.2

I have done the following on the httpd.conf :

KeepAlive On

KeepALiveTimeout 600

HTTP server:

The server is on a separate virtual machine on the server. Upon clicking 'LOGIN' on the index page, it is redirected to another php page which triggers a call by sending a message through a socket to a Asterisk(PBX) siting on another virtual machine on the server.

The php page waits for the asterisk call to end before redirecting the page to an intranet sitting on a separate server.

Triggering of call:

The phone call is triggered by an ASterisk(PBX) on an virtual machine on the server.

Comment: The call is triggered by an asterisk pbx. 

The system works from the pc/tablet. Issue arised only when using a phoen to access the website to trigger the call, after ansering and ending the call and being brough back to the phone browser, the 504 error pops up

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to check the access.log or error.log files? Perhaps you could run [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to study the packet transmission and reception - that could provide a clue to the issue you're facing. There is also a possibility that it may be an error on the API end of the call provider placing your call.

Comment: access.log show nothing out of the ordinary just the machines that have accessed.

Comment: Error log is showing a timezone specification error but nothing fancy.